# href属性に?queryのみを記述した場合の振舞

Tags: html

`http://example.com/test.php`があったとします。(PHPである必要はない)

```html
<pre>
<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>

<a href="?foo=bar">?foo=bar</a>
<a href="?fizz=buzz">?fizz=buzz</a>
</pre>
```

このとき、手元にあるユーザーエージェント(Chrome 41, w3m/0.5.3, GNU Wget 1.13.4)は、どれもリンクを以下のように展開します。

- `"?foo=bar"` => `http://example.com/test.php?foo=bar`
- `"?fizz=buzz"` => `http://example.com/test.php?fizz=buzz`

このような挙動について、HTMLや関連する規格の裏付けはあるのでしょうか。それとも、ユーザーエージェントの実装上の慣習に過ぎないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 6):

[RFC 3986 Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)です。 ([RFC 3986 日本語訳の複製](http://www.hcn.zaq.ne.jp/___/WEB/RFC3986-ja.html))

相対URIを解決するためのアルゴリズムは 「5.2.  Relative Resolution」にあります。また、実際の例が「5.4.  Reference Resolution Examples」にあるので抜萃します。

> ### 5.4.  Reference Resolution Examples
>
> Within a representation with a well defined base URI of
>
> ```
>  http://a/b/c/d;p?q
> ```
>
> #### 5.4.1.  Normal Examples
>
> a relative reference is transformed to its target URI as follows.
>
> ```
> "?y"            =  "http://a/b/c/d;p?y"
> "g?y"           =  "http://a/b/c/g?y"
> ```

よって、それぞれのユーザーエージェントは RFC 3986 の仕様に沿った挙動です。